# Image classifier model which predicts objects and it's relevant areas with a combination of words

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, algorithm-request, model-request

I have experience with image classification models such as CNN and Vision Transformers but this time I want to try a new thing (For me).

First please check the below image to understand what I want

[image]

In this picture I want to feed an image along with it's label (which is a string) and then I want to predict same string from my model.

In some cases there can be multiple strings with one image as we call multi class problem.

First I want to know if it's possible? Second which state of art CNN/Transformer model will be good for this model, Third has anyone worked on this before?

Comment: Can you please put your **main specific question** in the title? "Image classifier model which predicts string type labels" is not formulated as a question, so I would recommend you do that. Having said that, it seems that you want to predict one or more locations in the image and then you want to describe what is in those locations with more than one word, possibly. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes Sir, You truly understood my question. I want to predict information from specific locations which is the disease type and the surrounding information in an image.

Comment: And as You said sometimes there can be multiple locations (2 or 3) in an image and the model should describe these locations with more than one word.

Comment: @nbro Sir is it possible?  Is there any model developed before for this type of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task name is "Image captioning". That is the keyword for paper searching. Dataset, evaluation methods, and the state-of-the-art are all aggregated on the forum: [paperwithcode](https://paperswithcode.com/task/image-captioning).

Comment: Can I use these image caption generator models to generate multi captions from my image?

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not my field. However, I think it's possible since we have multi-label classifying, the captioning could also return multiple outputs. Or you can just use two models (in some cases, it's work).